# crosstab column group Restriction if field have null value in ireport

Tags: ireport, crosstab

cross tab column group Restriction if field have null value in ireport
ex..
   from Query if i getting this result.

```
name  x   y   z  age
```

---

```
abc   1   0   2   0
mac   2   1   1   1
```

when i to create cross tab with row group (Name,x) and column group (Age)
then result is

```
name   x   null  1
-------------------
abc    1    0    0
mac    2    0    1
```

i want to Restriction column (Null) to create new column in crosstab.
if column group is null or zero(0) column not to be create in cross tab